# Combinations of a Set Including Empty Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the best way of finding the combinations of a set of numbers where order does not matter and the numbers in the set cannot be repeated and you can include $0$ to $n$ numbers? The only idea I can come up with is:

$${n\choose 0} + {n\choose 1} + {n \choose 2} + \dots + {n \choose n} = \text{Number Of Possibilities} $$

Just to make sure everyone understands me, here's the answer with a simple set of $3$ numbers.

Set: $\left\lbrace 1, 2, 3 \right\rbrace$

Possible Outcomes:

$\{\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,2,3\}$

$\text{Number Of Possibilities} = 8$

Thanks!

Comment: You have $2^n$ possibilities, but what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're investigating is the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). A set of size $n$ always has a power set of size $2^n$.